# Exercise in R.Vakil 18.4.L: Ample line bundles and finite morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, projective-schemes

Here's the question:

> **R.Vakil, Exercise 18.4.L**: Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a base-point free invertible sheaf on a proper variety $X$, and hence induces some morphism $\phi: X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$. Then $\mathcal{L}$ is ample if and only if $\phi$ is finite.

So suppose that $\phi$ is finite, then by the hint in Ex 16.6.G, $\phi^{*}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ is ample and this is $\mathcal{L}$ (hope I am correct here).

But for the converse here is the hint:

> If $\phi$ is not finite, show that there is a curve $C$ contracted by $\pi$, using theorem 18.1.9. Show that $\mathcal{L}$ has degree 0 on $C$.

I am completely lost here. What is $\pi$? So I looked up at the theorem and it says

> **Theorem 18.1.9** Suppose $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ with $Y$ noetherian. Then $\pi$ is projective and has finite fibers if and only if it is finite. Equivalently $\pi$ is projective and quasifinite if and only if it is finite.

**Question 1**: How should I make sense of the ''contractible'' part and how do I use the theorem to prove it?

**Question 2**: Assume that the contractible part is done. I need to show that $\mathcal{L}$ has degree zero on $C$. Why? I tried Riemann-Roch but at least I can't get anything out of it. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I think the $\pi$ in the hint is just a typo for $\phi$.)

Note that for the direction you want to prove, we're assuming that $L$ is ample, which in particular implies that $X$ is projective.

**Question 1:** Since $X$ is projective, so is the morphism $\phi$. If $\phi$ isn't finite, Theorem 18.1.9 says it isn't quasifinite, so there must be some fibre $F$ of dimension $>0$. Then choose any curve $C \subset F$: this $C$ gets contracted by $\phi$.

**Question 2:** As you correctly observed, $L=\phi^* O(1)$. By definition of the pullback of line bundles, this means that $L$ is *trivial* when restricted to any fibre of $\phi$. Since $C$ is contained in a fibre, $L_{|C}$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is very helpful, except I have 2 questions:

1) Why does $X$ projective implies that the morphism $\phi$ is?

2) If $\phi$ is not quasifinite, it means there exists a point say $x\in \mathbb{P}^{n}$ such that $\phi^{-1}(x)$ is not finite. But why does this imply that the dimension is not $0$? The only result I know is that a noetherian scheme of dimension $0$ is a finite set, but then this means I need to show that $\phi^{-1}(x)$ is noetherian. But why should the fiber be noetherian?

Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh.... I just realised that the first question was silly: If $X$ is projective, then we have $f:X\rightarrow\text{Proj}(S.)$ an isomorphism. Then we have a morphism from $\phi\circ f^{-1}: \text{Proj}(S.)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n}$ that completes the commutative triangle, so $\phi$ is projective. Now I am stuck on my own second question.

Comment: For the second question just observe that $\phi^{-1}(x)$ is a projective variety, hence it is noetherian.